# How to get list box item reference in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cart

I have Listview control on webform.aspx page with below defination...

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="dispalyProducts">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server" id="table1">
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName") %>' />
<br/>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
                        <br/>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                        <br/>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add TO cart" OnClientClick="AddToCart('<%#Eval("ProductID") %>');return false;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Whent he program runs, it creates a list of product ID, name and a button.

I want to use this button as "add to cart" functionality. so when a user clicks on button, i want to call a javascript function with productID, and textbox value (as item id and quantity).

How can I pass these values to javascript function in listview.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick='AddToCart(\"<%#Eval("ProductID") %>\", \"<%#Eval("ProductName") %>\");return false;'/>
```

You can pass values as parameters to your js function.

Comment: It gives me error like....

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page

Comment: Please provide some additional information. How do you make request to the server? How do you handle request on the server-side? What event is fired on the server-side after your postback/callback?